# how to normalize with redux tool and creactentityAdapter

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

i using redux tool kit to build react native app and i try to normalize my data like this

```
const postEntitiy = new schema.Entity('post');

const postAdapter = createEntityAdapter({
  selectId: (post) => post._id,
});
const normalized = normalize(response.data, postEntitiy);
```

this is my resopose.data

```
Array [
  Object {
    "__v": 5,
    "_id": "6020b367cb94a91c9cd48c34",
    "comments": Array [],
    "date": "2021-02-08T03:43:35.742Z",
    "likes": Array [
      Object {
        "_id": "60216bd341b3744ce4b13bee",
        "user": "601f2d46017c85357800da96",
      },
    ],",
  },
]
```

and this is the error it throw

```
The entity passed to the `selectId` implementation returned undefined., You should probably provide
```

your own `selectId` implementation.,

```
The entity that was passed:, Object {
  "undefined": Object {
    "0": Object {
      "__v": 5,
      "_id": "6020b367cb94a91c9cd48c34",

      "comments": Array [],
      "date": "2021-02-08T03:43:35.742Z",
      "likes": Array [
        Object {
          "_id": "60216bd341b3744ce4b13bee",
          "user": "601f2d46017c85357800da96",
        },
      ],
    },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

As this is written the `postAdapter` and the `normalize` are independent of each other. What's happening here is that `normalize` is attempting the map the data into entities, but it ends up with the key as `undefined` because it is using the default key of `id` which has an `undefined` value.  Additionally you have an `array` of entities rather than just one.

The `postAdapter` then tries to find the `selectId` on this data which has already been normalized.  But the `postAdapter` is not looking at a single `post` object -- it is looking at the nested data created by `normalize`.  It is looking at the data structure `Object { "undefined": Object { "0": Object {...` from your error.  The `"undefined":` is caused by the bad `id` attribute and the `"0":` is because it is an array.

How you do write this correctly kind of depends on what it is that you are trying to do.  It's possible that `normalize` is not really necessary here.  It looks like the `likes` in `response.data` are already returning a `string` id for the like and the `user` instead of the deeply-nested data that the `normalizr` package is designed to flatten.  If you want to use `normalize` and have it work properly then you need to set the `idAttribute` on the `options` argument ([docs link](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr/blob/master/docs/api.md#entitykey-definition---options--)).

```
const postEntity = new schema.Entity('post', {}, {idAttribute: '_id'});

const normalized = data.map( o => normalize(o, postEntity));
```

`idAttribute` also accepts a `function`.  You can create a reusable id extractor function that pulls the `_id` property from any object with `{_id: string;}`.

```
const myIdExtractor = (object : {_id: string;}) => object._id;

const postEntity = new schema.Entity('post', {}, {idAttribute: myIdExtractor});

const normalized = data.map( o => normalize(o, postEntity));
```

That same id extractor function also works with `createEntityAdapter`.

```
const postAdapter = createEntityAdapter({
  selectId: myIdExtractor,
});
```